# How to check if a process definition key exist in camunda using services?

Tags: java, service, process, definition, camunda

I am trying to know if a process definition key exists in Camunda using its services.

I am aware of the rest api to fetch the details which is - GET /process-definition/key/{key}.

But instead of using rest calls, I would like to use the service's methods to achieve in my Java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checke the [RepositoryService](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/engine/RepositoryService.java). It will give you the `createProcessDefinitionQuery` method, which creates a Query builder that (among other attributes) accepts the process definition key.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! Was able to find the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Solution-

RepositoryService RS= execution.getProcessEngineServices().getRepositoryService();
ProcessDefinitionQuery processDefinitionQuery = RS.createProcessDefinitionQuery().processDefinitionKey("sample_key");
long count=  processDefinitionQuery.count();